# How to fix No resource identifier found for attribute '---' in android

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

In my app i want to use navigation drawer with swipe tab layout and i am following this [tutorial](https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/).But i am getting an exception from xml file called **error: No resource identifier found for attribute 
 'itemTextColor' in package 
 'com.example.samplenavigationdrawer'** How to clear it can any one tell me how to deal with it 
this is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Drawer With Swipe Tabs" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        >



    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">
     </FrameLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/stuff"
        app:itemTextColor="#000000"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_items"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        />



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tell me , why `android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"` ??

Comment: for overlapping with the drawer layout @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: I know, -24dp is not proper , by the by, if you comment `app:itemTextColor="#000000"` .Then running okay ?

Comment: But here i am passing the menu values with this `app` only.By not using the `app:menu` can u tell me how can i pass the menu items @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: where is `app:headerLayout` ??

Comment: I am not using this `app:headderlayout` can u tell me how to user it@IntelliJAmiya

Comment: I have downloaded this project, build and run it with no error. Are you try clean and re-build project. Which android studio, gradle you use ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE @DanhDC

Comment: try use ``android:itemTextColor="#000000"`` instead of ``app:itemTextColor="#000000"``

Comment: still error occurred

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Android Studio instead of Eclipse. Then you'll have less problems like this, and if you'll have some, there will be much more developers to help you as long as most android developers today use Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you bro for valuable sugession